# How do you guarantee that Arrays have a minimum level of recursion?

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion

I have some Arrays of varying length that are generated earlier in the code, consisting of subarrays of ordered pairs. If there is more than one pair, the output is an Array of Arrays. If there is only one pair, the output is a single Array.

What's a simple, consistent way to transform the output so that it is always at one level of recursion without writing something overly narrow to test for that exact occurrence? Right now I have:

```
output_array = [7, 5]
output_array = output_array.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
=> [[7, 5]]

output_array = [[7, 5], [6, 2]]
output_array = output_array.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
=> [[7, 5], [6, 2]]
```

Comment: What you have: `flatten.each_slice(2).to_a` is how I would do it as well.

Comment: I wish to thank the person responsible for the uptick on my earlier comment.  Unfortunately, what I suggested was incorrect.  It should have been: `output_array = (output_array.first.is_a? Array) ? output_array : [output_array]`

Comment: Was it? I can guarantee here that the `output_array` is an Array, though.

Comment: Yes, but the question is whether the elements of `output_array` are themselves arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less cute but much faster is to check if the inner element is an array and if not insert it into an empty array.

```
oa1.first.kind_of?(Array) ? oa1 : [oa1]
```

Mudasobwa excuse me for using your exellent solution to compare with.

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 10_000
oa1 = [5,7]
oa2 = [[5,7],[6,8]]
c1 = c2 = c3 = 0 
Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report {
    n.times do
      c1 += oa1.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a.first.first \
         +  oa2.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a.first.first
    end 
  }
  x.report {
    n.times do
      c2 += Hash[*oa1.flatten].to_a.first.first \
         +  Hash[*oa2.flatten].to_a.first.first
    end 
  }
  x.report {
    n.times do
      c3 += (oa1.first.kind_of?(Array) ? oa1 : [oa1]).first.first \
      +  (oa2.first.kind_of?(Array) ? oa2 : [oa2]).first.first \
    end 
  }
end

puts "c1 = #{c1}, c2 = #{c2}, c3 = #{c3}"
```

gives

```
   user     system      total        real
   0.063000   0.000000   0.063000 (  0.071007)
   0.062000   0.000000   0.062000 (  0.056006)
   0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.008001)
   c1 = 100000, c2 = 100000, c3 = 100000
```

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]** NB! This solution **fails** on *duplicate keys* (`[1,3,1,4]`), credits to Shawn Balestracci

Please use solution suggested by @peter below

---

Just out of curiosity, slicing by 2 always forces to think about hash-like structure, isn’t it? Hence, you might use:

```
Hash[*output_array.flatten].to_a
```

This is at least twice quicker:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 10_000
oa1 = [5,7]
oa2 = [[5,7],[6,8]]
c1 = c2 = 0 
Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report {
    n.times do
      c1 += oa1.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a.first.first \
         +  oa2.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a.first.first
    end 
  }
  x.report {
    n.times do
      c2 += Hash[*oa1.flatten].to_a.first.first \
         +  Hash[*oa2.flatten].to_a.first.first
    end 
  }
end

puts "c1 = #{c1}, c2 = #{c2}"


user     system      total        real
  0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.117027)
  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.064323)
c1 = 100000, c2 = 100000
```

Comment: Wow, that is a nice trick! Definitely saving this for later. It's complicated enough to read that it seems you'd want to hide it for extending Array as some method like `enforce_recursion(level,sub_el_length)`

Comment: As for me, it’s definitely _easier_ to read. Step by step it says: “flatten, make hash, turn it into an array” and _hash_ here is a keyword for “I’m interested in tuples.”

Comment: Duplicate keys will not give expected results, for example [1,3,1,4]

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci thank you, I updated the answer clarifying it’s actually wrong; @peter’s solution below seems to be the best approach then.